# Javascript Recursive String Append

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xml

I am having both simple and complex JSON data and converting it to XML with JavaScript recursive method like below:

```
var json = [
  {
    "id": "42cfb980-4221-e97f-f85a-f5fcf4d37f02",
    "name": "outer",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {},
    "subNodes": [
      {
        "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07a",
        "name": "inner",
        "value": "inner vlaue",
        "attributes": {},
        "subNodes": []
      }
    ]
  }
];

function prepareXmlOutput(appendTo, obj) {
        var i, k, attributeString = '';

        for (i in obj) {
            if (obj[i].attributes.length > 0) {
                for (k in obj[i].attributes) {
                    attributeString += ((obj[i].attributes[k].name != '') ? obj[i].attributes[k].name+'="'+obj[i].attributes[k].value+'"' : '') + ' ';
                }
            }
            if (obj[i].subNodes.length < 1) {
                if (obj[i].value == '') {
                    appendTo += '</' + obj[i].name + attributeString.replace(/~+$/,'') + '>';
                } else {
                    appendTo += '<' + obj[i].name + attributeString.replace(/~+$/,'') + '>' +obj[i].value+ '</' + obj[i].name + '>';
                }

            } else {
                appendTo += '<' + obj[i].name + attributeString.replace(/~+$/,'') + '>';

                appendTo += prepareXmlOutput(appendTo, obj[i].subNodes);

                appendTo += '</' + obj[i].name + '>';
            }
        }
        return appendTo;
    }

prepareXmlOutput('', json);
```

This produces xml perfectly fine but having one issue. Here is the XML it gave to me:

```
"<outer><outer><inner>inner vlaue</inner></outer>"
```

The issue is, it has the first node repeated. Why is it behaving like this? I tried a lot to debug it with dev tool and I found that the cursor directly goes to return statement after completing this stack:

```
appendTo += prepareXmlOutput(appendTo, obj[i].subNodes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
appendTo += prepareXmlOutput(appendTo, obj[i].subNodes);
```

with this:

```
appendTo += prepareXmlOutput('', obj[i].subNodes);
```

as it has to create the XML string for the subNodes independently from the accumulated `appendTo`. Then append the result (returned value) to it using `+=`. In your code the result get appended twice (get appended to `appendTo` inside the function then return the already appended result to be appended again using `+=`). For a depth of **N**, the outer element get repeated **N + 1** times, the second outer element get repeated **N** times, ... and so on until the inner element which will be not repeated.

An example of the error you had: consider `appendTo` is `'<outer>'` you pass it as argument to the function call, there `appendTo` gets appended to `'<inner>'` when the call end it return `'<outer><inner>'` which then you append to the previous value of `appendTo` (which is `'<outer>'`) using `+=`, so now `appendTo` becomes `'<outer><outer><inner>'` (the outer element repeated 2 times because it been passed to the call one time (one level below)) If there were N levels below, then `appendTo` will get passed to the call N times like this:

- Pass N°1: `appendTo = '<outer>'`
- Pass N°2: `appendTo = '<outer><outer><inner>'`
- Pass N°3: `appendTo = '<outer><outer><outer><inner><inner>'`
- ...

Comment: Great. It works fine but can you please elaborate it more? how it worked. and what is the issue with my implementation?

Comment: I guess you can take only `obj` as the input parameter and declare `appendTo` inside the function.

Comment: @ManishJangir I added an example. Not 100% accurate but you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some variety; you might as well do like this;

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": "42cfb980-4221-e97f-f85a-f5fcf4d37f02",
    "name": "outer",
    "value": "",
    "attributes": {},
    "subNodes": [
      {
        "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07a",
        "name": "in01",
        "value": "inner value",
        "attributes": {color:"red"},
        "subNodes": [{
                       "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07a",
                       "name": "in02",
                       "value": "more inner value",
                       "attributes": {color:"blue"},
                       "subNodes": [{
                                      "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07a",
                                      "name": "in03",
                                      "value": "most innest value",
                                      "attributes": {color:"pink"},
                                      "subNodes": []
                                    }]
                     }]
      },
      {
        "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07b",
        "name": "in11",
        "value": "another inner value",
        "attributes": {color:"orange"},
        "subNodes": [{
                       "id": "d0794639-5568-3728-11a4-676eb100b07a",
                       "name": "in12",
                       "value": "more inner value",
                       "attributes": {color:"brown"},
                       "subNodes": []
                     }]
      }
     ]
  }
],

parseXML = (a, r = "") => a.length ? parseXML(a.slice(1), r + Object.keys(a[0].attributes)
                                                                    .reduce((s,k) => s + " " + k + "=\"" + a[0].attributes[k] + "\"", "<" + a[0].name)
                                                                    + ">"
                                                                    + a[0].value
                                                                    + parseXML(a[0].subNodes,"")
                                                                    + "</"
                                                                    + a[0].name
                                                                    + ">")
                                   : r;
console.log(parseXML(json));
```